# The product rule in a non-abelian group of order $pq$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $p,q$ be two prime number such that $p\mid q-1$ and let $G$ be the non-abelian group of order $pq$. It is well known that the presentation of $G$ is
$$
G=\langle a,b\mid a^p=b^q=1, a^{-1}ba=b^r\rangle,
$$
where the integer $r$ satisfies $r\not\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ and $r^p\equiv1\pmod{q}$. In addition, we know that every element of $G$ is of the form $a^{\alpha}b^{\beta}$, where $\alpha\in\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$ and $\beta\in\{0,1,\ldots,q-1\}$.

**My question:** How we multiply two elements in $G$? In other words, what are the integers $x,y$ for which
$$
(a^{\alpha}b^{\beta})(a^{\gamma}b^{\delta})=a^xb^y
$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The conjugation map gives you the answer: if $a^{-1}ba=b^r$, then $ba=ab^r$. This allows you to 'pass' one $a$ from the right of the expression to the left. The outer $a$ and $b$ are unimportant, so we just want to worry about $b^\beta a^\gamma$. This is
$$ b^\beta a^\gamma=b^{\beta-1}(ab^r)a^{\gamma-1}.$$
Keeping pushing that $a$ past all of the $b$s, and we obtain
$$b^\beta a^\gamma=ab^{r\beta}a^{\gamma-1}.$$
We have to do that another $\gamma-1$ times, to obtain
$$b^\beta a^\gamma=a^\gamma b^{r^\gamma\beta}.$$
Putting the $\alpha$ and $\delta$ back in if you want, we obtain
$$a^\alpha b^\beta a^\gamma b^\delta=a^{\alpha+\gamma}b^{r^\gamma\beta+\delta}.$$

Comment: Thanks @David A. Craven (again...)!

Comment: No worries. I'm waiting for my computer to decompose some group representations.